# Adding value to DataGridView column when new record is created

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am using Visual Studio 2017/VB/Winforms and I have a `DataGridView` which is using a `BindingSource` to connect to an Access database.

It works well, but I need to programmatically add a value to one of the fields/columns which is hidden from the user when a new record is added. I'm quite sure this is a simple question, but I have been struggling with it for hours trying to figure out which event is the right one to use. Is it a `DataGridView` event I'm looking for or a `BindingSource` event?

Here is the code I thought would do the job, but it still gives me an error saying that ProjectID cannot be Null

```
    Private Sub StoresDataGridView_DefaultValuesNeeded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowEventArgs) _
                Handles StoresDataGridView.DefaultValuesNeeded
        e.Row.Cells("colProjectID").Value = 1
    End Sub
```

Please help me figure this out, as again, I am sure it's something really simple that I'm missing. I also tried setting a break point in that event, and it doesn't even seem to be firing.

I also tried adding this to the form's Load event, and did not get any errors when the form loaded, but when trying to add a new record I still get the same error.

`StoresDataGridView.Columns("colProjectID").DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = 1`

Comment: As it turned out, `StoresDataGridView_DefaultValuesNeeded` was the correct event, it just wasnt firing because the grid had `AllowUserToAddRows` was set to `False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the grid's `RowValidating` event like this:

`StoresDataGridView.Rows(StoresDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("colProjectID").Value = 1`